# Keras: "must compile model before using it" despite compile() is used

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, runtime-error, sequential

I want to create and train a CNN model in Keras for classification of banknotes. Creating models works fine with simple tutorials but not with the architecture I adopt from this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5539635/).
Keras outputs: `RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')` after `fit_generator()` is called.

I use the tensorflow backend if that is of relevance.

---

Model is defined in `model.py`:

```
from keras.layers import ...
model = Sequential() 
model.add(some_layer)

... #according to the paper

model.add(some_layer)
model.add(Dense(#output_classes, activation='softmax') #last layer

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The `model` is then used from `start_train.py`:

```
from model import model as m

#some ImageGenerator stuff as input

m.fit_generator( #training on train_data
        train_pics,
        steps_per_epoch=#steps,
        epochs=#epochs,
        validation_data=test_pics,
```

As far as I understood it the process in Keras is as follows:

1. Define model
2. Compile model
3. (If wanted evaluate() & summary() can be used now after the compilation)
4. Fit model
5. Evaluate model.

I tested if `model.py` is accessed before calling `fit_generator()` and it works properly. I'm out of ideas and wondering what I'm doing wrong especially since the same set-up works fine with a basic model/architecture.

Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Does it not work if you run `model.compile()` inside the `start_train.py` script?

Comment: No, same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found my mistake - explanation for future reference.

The error origniates back in `compile()` where the first if-statement says:

```
if not self.built:
    # Model is not compilable because
    # it does not know its number of inputs
    # and outputs, nor their shapes and names.
    # We will compile after the first
    # time the model gets called on training data.
return
```

So I specified `input_shape=` and `input_format=`in the first `Conv2D` layer and everything works fine.

Comment: just to add a concrete example. to remove the error add input_shape in first conv2d layer.                                                                                                             
   new_model = Sequential()
   new_model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',padding='same',input_shape=(32,32,3)))

Answer (score 6):

If ever someone ends up with the same error code here is maybe a way to fix it. So I was using a generator and was getting the "Must compile" error even tho everything was fine. I was able to fix it by doing a model.fit(x,y) on a single batch before launching my fit_generator and everything worked fine after that. I don't know if this helps anyone but yeah!

Comment: I have experienced the same issue due to the use of generators (like you), and your workaround works like a charm. Between, hopefully, they fix this issue in the next releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can run evaluate on a small set and that would fix it.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(use your own learning rate)
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy']))
```

Comment: Your code can't run as is and explaining why your solution work would be welcomed